# Using D3.js on Reveal.js slides

Tags: d3.js, reveal.js

I am trying to use your charts on a Reveal.js presentation, but the tooltip format is changed - I guess by the Reveal CSS.

Have you already tried this "combination"?

Thank you

```
function myData() {
var series1 = [];
for(var i =1; i < 100; i ++) {
    series1.push({
        x: i, y: 100 / i
    });
}

return [
    {
        key: "Series #1",
        values: series1,
        color: "#0000ff"
    }
];
}

nv.addGraph(function() {
var chart = nv.models.lineChart();

chart.xAxis
    .axisLabel("X-axis Label");

chart.yAxis
    .axisLabel("Y-axis Label")
    .tickFormat(d3.format("d"))
    ;

d3.select("#sample1")
    .datum(myData())
    .transition().duration(500).call(chart);

nv.utils.windowResize(
        function() {
            chart.update();
        }
    );

return chart;
});
```

Comment: Could you give us some more information please? I haven't tried it and have no idea what the problem you're describing is.

Comment: The NVD3 tooltip that shows up when you make mouse hover the chart lines doesn't show up with the correct format.

Comment: Ok, so you're using NVD3? Could you post a complete example please?

Comment: <section>
     <svg id="sample1" style='height:600px;width:800px'/>
     <script src="js/sample1.js"></script>
    </section>

Comment: function myData() {
 var series1 = [];
 for(var i =1; i < 100; i ++) {
  series1.push({
   x: i, y: 100 / i
  });
 }

 return [
  {
   key: "Series #1",
   values: series1,
   color: "#0000ff"
  }
 ];
}

nv.addGraph(function() {
 var chart = nv.models.lineChart();

 chart.xAxis
  .axisLabel("X-axis Label");

 chart.yAxis
  .axisLabel("Y-axis Label")
  .tickFormat(d3.format("d"))
  ;

 d3.select("#sample1")
  .datum(myData())
  .transition().duration(500).call(chart);

 nv.utils.windowResize(
   function() {
    chart.update();
   }
  );

 return chart;
});

Comment: Sorry...I guess the format is not very good.

Comment: You can edit your question and include the code there, add 4 spaces at the beginning of each line, so the code is properly formatted.